# Install specific version of X11 for xmonad?

Tags: x11, package-management, apt, xmonad, cabal

I wanted to compile `xmonad` from source, so I checked out the code and ran the first command from the `README`.

```
$ runhaskell Setup.lhs configure --user --prefix=$HOME
Configuring xmonad-0.12...
Setup.lhs: At least the following dependencies are missing:
X11 >=1.5 && <1.7
```

Apparently haskell wants a specific version of `X11`. This kind of scares me, as whenever I touch video-specific items like `Xorg` or video drivers, I tend to completely bork my system.

1. Is it safe to install a specific newer version of `X11`?
2. How would I do so? Is it possible to use `apt-get`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm still not sure how this worked, but I was able to use `cabal` to install the correct version of `X11`. It doesn't seem to conflict with the version reported by `Xorg -version`.

```
cabal install x11
```